# Column-major unload in Redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'd like to dump stuff from Redshift into S3 in column-major format (so one file per column).  Oddly, I have thus far found nothing here or elsewhere on the internet about anybody wanting to do the same.

My question is whether Redshift/PostgreSQL has any support for loading & unloading data in a columnar format, and, if not, whether anything else does.  It seems so strange to me that this wouldn't be a thing--the data is stored column-major, isn't it?  I know, I know, "slices/nodes", but wouldn't sortkey (along with the necessary assumption that the incoming data is sorted) handle that?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Faster loading? Some external processing?

Comment: Both.  I'm trying to make quick-as-possible distributed (Spark) app that would process and convert columns to a more ML-friendly format.

Comment: Unload returns a row-major file, broken up into chunks every so many rows.  What I'd like would be something column-major (ideally, one column per file).  This would make ingest faster.  If nothing exists it's fine, I just thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 0):

There is no in-built capability to `UNLOAD` in a columnar format.

However, the Amazon Redshift `UNLOAD` command takes a `SELECT` statement, so it could be run several times, each with a different column.

From [UNLOAD documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html):

```
UNLOAD ('select_statement')
TO 's3://object_path_prefix'
[ WITH ] CREDENTIALS [AS] 'aws_access_credentials' 
[ option [ ... ] ]
```